# Is there a way to configure the Ask function so that input fields can be optional?

Tags: gui-construction, wolfram-cloud, inputfield, form-building

I see that FormFunction includes settings that could work, but I can't seem to find any way to get it to work within the "Ask" framework.

Related: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedWebFormCreation.html

Among many things that I tried, this does not work:

```
Ask[{responseName, prompt} -> <|Interpreter -> "String", 
     "Required" -> False|>];
```

It no longer warns that the field is required, but it repeats the Ask forever until the field is filled.

Thanks for any guidance!

Comment: Hi Kuba.  Setting a default value is a step in the right direction, but different from making a field optional.  It doesn't solve my issue in this case.  I've continued to fiddle with it, but have not solved it.  I don't think optional fields are supported yet.  Thanks!

Comment: But what exactly do you expect from optional field? You said it repeats the question, now it is solved. I know it is a trick but why doesn't it fit your needs?

Comment: I was hoping that the user could leave that paricular field blank and proceed the the form.

Comment: But user can leave it blank.

Answer (score 2):

Default value syntax works here too so you can use it:

```
CloudDeploy[
 AskFunction[Ask["key" -> "String" -> "default"]]
]
```

If you want to check whether one skipped that entry you can use unique or empty string there and match after submission.